# WebStorm doesn't recognize Ionic HTML elements/tags - e.g. "Cannot find name 'ion'"

Tags: html, templates, ionic-framework, webstorm

WebStorm 2018.3.2

As in the title - My WebStorm doesn't recognize Ionic HTML elements/tags.
Almost all HTML is highlighted and the program says e.g.

> "Cannot find name 'ion'"

or

> "Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'".

[image: Check the screenshot]

Comment: *"my version is the newest."* -- Latest is **2019.3** while yours is **2018.3.2** (1 year old version).

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that `node_modules\@ionic\core` and `node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist` are not excluded from indexing. Un-excluding them (**Mark directory as/Not excluded**) should make things better.

For the full support of ionic 4 components I'd suggest upgrading webStorm to the most recent version.

Comment: I have already done what you are suggesting, but this doesn't help.
My node_ modules are not exluded.
I thought, my version is the newest.. hmm.. So I need to check that. It defenitely is not old though..